# Prove the coplanarity of four vectors

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Four points A, B , C , D with position vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}, \vec{c}, \vec{d}$ respectively are coplanar iff $3\vec{a} -2\vec{b}+ \vec{c}-2 \vec{d}=\vec{0}$

**progress**

We know that four vectors  $\vec{a},\vec{b}, \vec{c}, \vec{d}$ are coplanar iff

$x\vec{a} +y\vec{b}+ z\vec{c}+t \vec{d}=0$ and $x+y+z+t=0$

How can I prove the result. Please help

Comment: Something peculiar about your $x+y+x+y+t=0$. Why are $x$ and $y$ repeated, $t$ isn't, and $z$ isn't there at all?

Comment: If you mean that $\vec{a}=\vec{OA}$, etc. with $O$ the origin, this proposition is evidently **erroneous**. Take for example colinear vectors $\vec{a}=(1,0,0),\vec{b}=(2,0,0),\vec{c}=(3,0,0),\vec{d}=(4,0,0)$... we don't have $3\vec{a} -2\vec{b}+ \vec{c}-2 \vec{d}=\vec{0}.$

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for point out my mistake, correction has been done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have
$3\vec{OA}-2\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}-2\vec{OD}=0$

or, Using Chasles relation,

$2\vec{BA}+\vec{DA}+\vec{DC}=0$

thus

$2\vec{BD}+3\vec{DA}+\vec{DC}=0$

and

$\vec{DC}=2\vec{DB}-3\vec{DA}$

which means that the point $C$ is in the plane defined by the points
$D , A$ and $B$  or by the vectors

$\vec{DA}$ and $\vec{DB}$.